# superclass mismatch for class User - inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord, superclass

I am trying to figure out my superclass mismatch error. All the posts I've read about this describe the problem as being that User is defined twice as a class in my application.

In my case, it isn't defined twice. I have a services folder and within that I have a user folder (for user service classes). In that user folder, I have a file called organisation_mapper_service.rb, with:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      class OrganisationMapperService
        def self.call(user: u)
          new(user: user).call
        end

        def initialize(user: u)
          self.user = user
        end

        def call
          if matching_organisation.present?
            # user.organisation_request.new(organisation_id: matching_organisation.id)
            # user.update_attributes!(organisation_id: matching_organisation.id)
          else
            #SystemMailer.unmatched_organisation(user: user).deliver_now
          end
        end

        private

        attr_accessor :user

        def matching_organisation
          User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user).matching_organisation
        end
      end
    end
```

Separate to that, I have my user model which defines user as:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
```

I thought it should be fine to define the service class in the way I have because it inherits from ActiveRecord::Base rather than ApplicationRecord.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here? Where else could I look for a second definition of User?

**TAKING SERGIO'S SUGGESTION**

I change the user organisation mapper service to open as follows:

```
class User::OrganisationMapperService < ActiveRecord::Base
```

But that then gives an error with my Users::OrgRequestsController which has new defined as follows:

```
def new
    @all_organisations    = Organisation.select(:title, :id).map { |org| [org.title, org.id] }
    @org_request = OrgRequest.new#form(OrganisationRequest::Create)

    matched_organisation = User::OrganisationMapperService.new(current_user).matching_organisation
    @org_request.organisation_id = matched_organisation.try(:id)
  end
```

the error message then says:

```
PG::UndefinedTable at /users/4/org_requests/new
ERROR:  relation "user_organisation_mapper_services" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"user_organisation_mapper...
```

**TAKING SERGIO'S SUGGESTION (exactly) **

I change my service class to:

```
class User::OrganisationMapperService
```

But then I get an error that says:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

That error highlights this line of my service class:

```
def initialize(user: u)
      self.user = user
    end
```

I don't know what to do about that because I clearly have a user if there is an inheritance from user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even once you solve all your other issues, you actually have an infinite recursion going on.

```
User::OrganisationMapperService.call(user: User.first)
```

Is equivalent to calling:

```
User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user: User.first).call
```

Which internally calls `matching_organisation`, so is sort of equivalent to:

```
User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user: User.first).matching_organisation
```

Meanwhile, `matching_organisation` calls

```
User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user).matching_organisation
```

It's just going to go round and round in circles.

The only reason it doesn't is because of the `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` error.  This is because it should be `User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user: user)` rather than `User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user)` in your `matching_organisation` method.

**Update in response to comment:**

From what I understand, the `User::OrganisationMapperService` is a service class that does the job of finding some `Organisation` and then performing some sort of work.

The `User::OrganisationMapperService#matching_organisation` method should actually contain the code that returns the matching organisation for the given user.  The implementation will completely depend on how you have structured your database, but I'll give a couple of examples to put you on the right track or give you ideas.

First, Your `organisations` table may have a `user_id` column.  In this case you could do a simple query on the `Organisation` model and perform a search using the user's id:

```
class User::OrganisationMapperService
  def matching_organisation
    # find the organisation and cache the result
    @matching_organisation ||= ::Organisation.where(user_id: user).first
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you may have some sort of join table where there may be multiple Users at an Organisation (just for this example let us call this table 'employments'):

```
class Employment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organisation
end
```

We can add [scopes (this is a must read)](http://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/) to the `Organisation` model to assist with the query:

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :employments
  has_many :users, through: :employments 

  scope :for_user, ->(user) {
    # return organisations belonging to this user
    joins(:users).merge( Employment.where(user_id: user) )
  }

end
```

Then finally, the `OrganisationMapperService#matching_organisation` method becomes:

```
class User::OrganisationMapperService
  def matching_organisation
    # find the organisation and cache the result
    @matching_organisation ||= ::Organisation.for_user(user).first
  end
end
```

Comment: hmmm - sounds like I've gotten a bit ahead of myself. Can you suggest something for me to try to learn about to have another go at setting this out? I spent my day reading about recursion, and I can see your point, but now I'm not clear on what to do in order to approach this in a better way.

Comment: I've update my answer with some examples that may help.  Obviously I can only infer what you are trying to achieve.  Hopefully, my examples are close to what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: Also, besides recommending the link to [Mastering ActiveRecord and AREL](http://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/) I think you've already done your research on service objects and what not.  I haven't actually seen too many good posts that actually go into detail on what makes a good service object.  They mainly describe *what* they are which admittedly isn't very helpful.  They all refer to single responsibility and dependency injection and other `good` design practices... really just use your own intuition and don't overthink things too much... that can be a trap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'll give it another go

Answer (score 0):

You *are* defining `User` class with two separate parent classes. Don't do that.

It should be

```
class User::OrganisationMapperService
```

This way, your existing `User` class will be loaded and used, rather than a new one created.

> I thought it should be fine to define the service class in the way I have because it inherits from ActiveRecord::Base rather than ApplicationRecord.

The service class in your example doesn't inherit from anything.

Comment: Do you mean that I should write it as you have, or should I have:class User::OrganisationMapperService < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: Why do you think you need the service to inherit from activerecord?