# Rails 5 - service class to find users who have email addresses that match an organisation's domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, service

I am trying to learn how to use Rails 5 (generally) but specifically, I'm trying to learn how to use service classes.

I'm trying to write a service class that maps a user's given email address (user's have an attribute called :email) to organisation's domain names. Organisations have attributes called :email_format. I use that attribute to hold the part of the email address that follows the "@".

When a user creates an account, I want to take their email address that they use to sign up with, and match the bit after the @ to each of the organisations that I know about and try to find a matching one.

My attempts at this are plainly wrong, but I'm struggling to figure out why.

I have resources called User, Organisation and OrgRequest. The associations are:

User

```
belongs_to :organisation, optional: true
has_one :org_request
```

Organisation

```
has_many :org_requests 
has_many :users
```

OrgRequest

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :organisation
```

I have tried to write a service class as:

```
class User::OrganisationMapperService #< ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.call(user: u)
      new(user: user).call
    end

    def initialize(user: u)
      self.user = user
    end

    def call
      if matching_organisation.present?
        # user.organisation_request.new(organisation_id: matching_organisation.id)
        # user.update_attributes!(organisation_id: matching_organisation.id)
      else
        #SystemMailer.unmatched_organisation(user: user).deliver_now
      end
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :user

    def matching_organisation
      # User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user).matching_organisation
      User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user: user)
    end

end
```

I then have an org requests controller with:

```
class Users::OrgRequestsController < ApplicationController

    before_action      :authenticate_user!, except: [:new, :create, :requested]
  before_action      :set_org_request, only: [:approved, :rejected, :removed]

  # skip_before_action :redirect_for_unrequested_organisation
  # skip_before_action :redirect_for_unknown_organisation

  def index
    organisation = Organisation.find_by(owner_id: current_user.id)
    return redirect_to(user_path(current_user.id)) if organisation.nil?

    @org_requests = organisation.org_requests
  end

  def new
    @all_organisations    = Organisation.select(:title, :id).map { |org| [org.title, org.id] }
    @org_request = OrgRequest.new#form(OrganisationRequest::Create)

    matched_organisation = User::OrganisationMapperService.new(current_user).matching_organisation
    @org_request.organisation_id = matched_organisation.try(:id)
  end

  def create
    @org_request = OrgRequest.new(org_request_params)
    @org_request.user_id = current_user.id

    if @org_request.save
      OrgRequest::ProcessService.new(org_request).process
      return redirect_to(user_path(current_user),
        flash[:alert] => 'Your request is being processed.')
    else
      # Failure scenario below
      @all_organisations    = Organisation.select(:title, :id).map { |org| [org.title, org.id] }

      render :new
    end
  end

  def requested
    # Need help  - if this is contained in form inputs - how do i stop from overriding the submit path?

    redirect_to(user_path(current_user))
    #not sure about this - a similar redirect isnt required for articles or project create
  end

  def approve
    @org_request = current_user.organisation.org_requests.find(params[:id])

    if @org_request.state_machine.transition_to!(:approved)
      flash[:notice] = "You've added this member."
      redirect_to org_requests_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "You're not able to manage this organisation's members"
      redirect_to :index
    end
  end

  def remove
    @org_request = current_user.organisation.org_requests.find(params[:id])

    if @org_request.state_machine.transition_to!(:removed)
      flash[:notice] = "Removed from the organisation."
      redirect_to action: :index
      # format.html { redirect_to :index }
      # format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      # redirect_to action: :show, id: project_id
      # add mailer to send message to article owner that article has been approved
    else
      flash[:error] = "You're not able to manage this organisation's members"
      redirect_to(user_path(current_user))
      # redirect_to action: :show, id: project_id
    end
  end

  def decline
    @org_request = current_user.organisation.org_requests.find(params[:id])

    if @org_request.state_machine.transition_to!(:declined)
      flash[:notice] = "You're not eligible to join this organisation"
      redirect_to action: :index
      # redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
      # format.html { redirect_to :index }
      # redirect_to action: :show, id: organisation_request.profile
      # add mailer to send message to article owner that article has been approved
    else
      flash[:error] = "You're not able to manage this organisation's members"
      redirect_to(user_path(current_user))
      # redirect_to action: :show, id: organisation_request.profile
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_org_request
      @org_request = OrgRequest.find(params[:id])
      authorize @org_request
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def org_request_params
      params.require(:org_request).permit(:organisation_id, :name) # Need help - not sure if I need to put user id and organisation id in this permission
    end

end
```

I can't figure out another approach to this. When I try this, I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

The error message highlights line 7 of my service class, which has:

```
 def initialize(user: u)
      self.user = user
    end
```

I have previously asked questions about this problem here: [superclass mismatch for class User - inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228017/superclass-mismatch-for-class-user-inheriting-from-activerecordbase)

but I haven't managed to catch the drift of the advice or what is causing the problem. This attempt is a mash up of suggestions that I have gleaned from at least 10 different tutorials - so I appreciate that its highly unlikely to be correct, but I'm struggling to understand how the different parts of this work to know what to try differently.

Can anyone give me a steer on how to try to progress this attempt?

**Organisation mapper decorator** has:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  class OrganisationMapper < ::ApplicationDecorator

    def matching_organisation
      @matching_organisation ||= Organisation.by_email_format(email_format).first
    end

    def email_format
      user.email.split('@').last
    end

    private

    def user
      @model
    end
  end
end
```

**Application decorator** has:

```
class ApplicationDecorator
  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  private
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    args.empty? ? @model.send(method) : @model.send(method, *args)
  end
end
```

**Org request service class** has:

```
class OrgRequest::CreateService < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :org_request

    def self.call(user_id: user_id, organisation_id: org_id)
      new(user_id: user_id, organisation_id: organisation_id).call
    end

    def initialize(user_id: user_id, organisation_id: org_id)
      self.user_id         = user_id
      self.organisation_id = organisation_id
    end

    def call
      self.org_request \
       = OrgRequest.new(user_id: current_user.id,
                                  organisation_id: params[:org_request][:organisation_id])

      if org_request.save
        # send the email
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end


end
```

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I have tried every variation on this that I can think of. Nothing I'm trying makes any sense to me but I can't make sense out of any examples that I can find.

My service class currently has:

```
class User::OrganisationMapperService #< ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.call(user: u)
      new(user: user).call
    end

    def initialize(user: u)
      self.user = user
    end

    def call
      # if matching_organisation.present?
        # user.org_request.new(organisation_id: matching_organisation.id)
        # if found create a request for that user to enter the organisation
        if match_domain.present?
          OrgRequest.create(user: @user, organisation_id: @organisation_domain.organisation.id) #if organisation

        # user.update_attributes!(organisation_id: matching_organisation.id)
      else
        #SystemMailer.unmatched_organisation(user: user).deliver_now
      end
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :user

    # def matching_organisation
    #   # User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user).matching_organisation
    #   User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user: user).Organisation.by_email_format(email_format).first
    # end

    # def matching_organisation
    #   @matching_organisation ||= Organisation.by_email_format(email_format).first
    # end

    def user_domain
      user.email.split('@').last
    end

    def organisation_domain
      @organisation = Organisation.find_by(email_format: user_domain)
     end

    # def user_email_domain
    # # extract domain from users email
    #  user_email_domain = @user.email.split('@').last
    # end
    def match_domain
      return unless @user_domain == @organisation.email_format
    end

     # find an organisation with a matching domain
    # end

end
```

It's plainly wrong. The error message says:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `organisation' for #<User::OrganisationMapperService:0x007faec6ec06b8>
```

I can't make sense of the error message either because I have put '@' in front of every instance of 'organisation' just to try to make that error go away. It doesn't.

Please help.

**ANOTHER COMPLETELY SENSELESS ERROR MESSAGE**

I had another go at trying to write the method to check whether an email domain matches an organisation's email format in my service class.

The call method now has:

```
def call
      if user_domain == Organisation.email_format.any?
          OrgRequest.create(user: @user, organisation_id: @organisation_domain.organisation.id) #if organisation
      else
      end
    end
```

The error message in the console says:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `email_format' for #<Class:0x007faec72d8ac0>
```

That has to be nonsense because my organisation table has an attribute in it called :email_format. In the console, I can write:

```
o = Organisation.first.email_format
  Organisation Load (3.3ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations" ORDER BY "organisations"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

That gives me the result I'm looking for.

I'm trying (to my wits end) to learn how rails communicates. I can't make any sense of any of it.

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

Next guess of a go at the call method:

```
def call
      if user_domain == organisation_domain?
          OrgRequest.create(user: @user, organisation_id: @organisation_domain.organisation.id) #if organisation

      else
      end
```

Produces this error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `organisation_domain?' for #<User::OrganisationMapperService:0x007faec3be3600>:
```

I can't seem to find a single form of expression that doesnt produce this error.

Comment: The error does say that your OrganisationMapperService class does not have organisation_domain? method... add it there

Comment: The method organisaiton_domain is defined in the OrganisationMapperService. The error message doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: I have; def organisation_domain
      @organisation = Organisation.find_by(email_format: user_domain)
     end. I only added the 'a' at the beginning to try and make an error message disappear. I don't think it should be there.

Comment: Maybe try to upload the sample app to GitHub which will give better visibility to others about the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a session on code mentor. This is the answer. I hope it might help someone else who is trying to learn.

```
class User::OrganisationMapperService #< ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.call(user: u)
      new(user: user).call
    end

    def initialize(user: u)
      self.user = user
    end

    def call
      if organisation_domain.present?
          OrgRequest.create(user: @user, organisation_id: organisation_domain.id) #if organisation

      else
      end
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :user


    def user_domain
      user.email.split('@').last
    end

    def organisation_domain
      @organisation ||= Organisation.find_by(email_format: user_domain)
     end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in the following line:

```
matched_organisation = User::OrganisationMapperService.new(current_user).matching_organisation
```

It should be this instead:

```
matched_organisation = User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user: current_user).matching_organisation
```

Comment: Hi @leandroico - thanks for this, but matched_organisation hasn't been uncommented for the last 20 attempts at this. I'll keep trying to solve the current problem for now.